# touch a directory in python (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Is there a way to "touch" a existing directory in Linux using python so that its modtime becomes the current system time?

From the command line this is the equivalent of `touch $directory`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`os.utime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime) will allow you to set the atime and mtime of an existing filesystem object, defaulting to the current date and time.

```
os.utime(path)
```

Comment: Works for py3 but py2, have to specify the atime mtime tuple

Comment: Actually, for py2, while you do need a 2nd argument, it can be simply `None` to get the current date and time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with [`os.utime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.utime):

```
now = time.time()
os.utime('/tmp/marker', (now, now))
```

Comment: No need to cast now time.time() to int

Comment: No need to use `time.time()` at all -- as of Python 2.0, you can get the same effect with simply `os.utime('/tmp/marker', None)`.